# Find a tangent between line segment and circle

Tags: javascript, math

I have a line segment A (x1, y1), B (x2, y2) and a circle with the center C (x3, y3). Also I have radius of the circle. How do I get tangents?

[image: This is what I am trying to make]

These tangent lines should always be parallel to line segment.

P.S. Sorry if it is doesn't make sense to you, I am very very bad at math. Ask me any questions, I just don't know what else be needed to solve this task. Thanks.

Comment: @adelriosantiago HTML5 canvas and javascript. I want to draw 2 lines parallel to line segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segment defines direction vector

```
 D = (dx, dy) = (b.x - ax, b.y - a.y)
 dlen = Length(D) = Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
```

Radius-vector is perpendicular to tangent and it's length is R. Let circle center is (0,0) (we will make correction after). So

```
 x * x + y * y = R^2
 x * dx + y * dy = 0  //scalar product
```

Solving this system for unknown x,y, we have

```
 x =  +- R * dy / dlen
 y =  -+ R * dx / dlen
```

And after correction two base points of tangents are

```
px1 = x3 + R * dy / dlen  
py1 = y3 - R * dx / dlen 

px2 = x3 - R * dy / dlen  
py2 = y3 + R * dx / dlen
```

Direction vectors for these tangents are D, so you can define second points for tangents as

```
px1_2 = x3 + R * dy / dlen + dx 
py1_2 = y3 - R * dx / dlen + dy
```

And the first tangent is line through (px1, py1) and (px1_2, py1_2)

Note that solution works for any direction of segment (including horizontal and vertical)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've tried to implement your solution but I believe I've made a mistake somewhere. Here is what I got https://imgur.com/sb4kcuI. Line segment in the circle is always perpendicular to initial line segment. Can you tell me please where did I make mistake?

Comment: Could you show your implementation? (for example, in any online IDE) Radius to tangent point should be perpendicular to the tangent. What `Line segment in the circle` do you mean?

Comment: Seems that base point for tangent is calculated properly. But how do you draw that tangent?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eo8j953s/1/. It is my javascript implementation of your algorithm. Line segment in the circle is the green line on image

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eo8j953s/2/. I updated fiddle. I draw tangent with moveTo, lineTo functions of canvas, where moveTo is the start of the line and lineTo is the end

Comment: OK, I understand. You draw line between two tangent points, while you have to draw two separate lines for every tangent point. See my edit

Comment: Can you please send me updated link if you made this in jsFiddle? If not where can I see your edit?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eo8j953s/3/ but I don't see any plotting (I am not familiar with JS console)

Comment: There isn't any, I've pasted only js code there. But I got the idea. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for the tangent lines with slope == the slope of the line. I will detail the algorithm and I leave the actual code to you.

1. So first lineslope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1).
2. Next a circle with radius r centered at (x3, y3) can be described by the parametric equations x = r*cos(t) + x3; y = r*sin(t) + y3.
3. The slope of the circle at a given t is (dy/dt)/(dx/dt) = -cos(t)/sin(t) = -1/tan(t).
4. Set -1/tan(t) = lineslope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1). Solving for t yields t = (pi / 2) - arctan(-(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)). (This should produce two values for t on [0, 2pi] which will be the two places the slope of the tangent line equals the slope of your segment).
5. Plug the value for t you just calculated into the circle equations from (3), and you will have the point (x4, y4) on the circle where the tangent line has the same slope as your line segment.
6. The equation of the tangent line is then just y - y4 = lineslope*(x-x4)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain line number 2 at : x = r cos(t) + x3. How do I get t and what does r cos mean? Is it multiply? Next what is dy and dy? Sorry if it is obvious things but as I said I am really bad at math.

Comment: Yes r cos(t) meant r*cos(t), I have edited to add the asterisks. t is just the parameter, a dummy variable for the parameterization of x and y. Google parametric equations and it should be clear.

Comment: I've already implemented @MBo solution, but thank you anyway for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Write the equation of the line AB in the implicit form

```
a X + b Y + c = 0
```

where the coefficients are normalized so that `a² + b² = 1`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form

The two requested tangents are parallel to AB, with equation

```
a X + b Y + c' = 0
```

and it suffices to express that the distance of the lines to the center of the circle is `R`,

```
|a Xc + b Yc + c'| = R
```

giving two solutions in `c'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already used another algorithm to solve this, but I appreciate your answer!